# how to pass data from one function to another, in one controller using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have one post, if the post is successful it will output data2 "$ result ['STATUS_CODE'] == 200", how do you pass the newly obtained data to another function?

```
public function createPassanger(Request $request){
        $api       = new Api;
        $input     = $request->all();
        $platform  = "W";
        $id_flight = Session::get('id_flight');
        $url       = config::get('constants.url')."api/passanger/add";

        //this is my post
        $post = array(
            "passanger_name"      => $input['name'], 
            "passanger_email"     => $input['email'],
            "passanger_passport"  => $input['passport'],
            "id_flight"           => $id_flight,
            "platform"            => $platform
        );

        $result = $api->post($url, $post);
        //this is results of the post
        if($result['STATUS_CODE'] == 200){
            $summary['id_summary']         = $result['DATA']['id_summary'];
            $summary['id_passanger']       = $result['DATA']['id_passanger'];
            $summary['id_flight']          = $result['DATA']['id_flight'];
            $summary['passanger_name']     = $result['DATA']['passanger_name'];
            $summary['passanger_passport'] = $result['DATA']['passanger_passport'];
            $summary['passanger_email']    = $result['DATA']['passanger_email'];
            $summary['order_id']           = $result['DATA']['order_id'];
            $summary['check_in']           = $result['DATA']['check_in'];
            $summary['status_booking']     = $result['DATA']['status_booking'];
            $summary['status']             = $result['DATA']['status'];
            $summary['member_id']          = $result['DATA']['member_id'];
            $summary['airlines_id']        = $result['DATA']['airlines_id'];
            $summary['airlines_name']      = $result['DATA']['airlines_name'];
            $summary['flight_no']          = $result['DATA']['flight_no'];
            $summary['airport_id']         = $result['DATA']['airport_id'];
            $summary['airport_name']       = $result['DATA']['airport_name'];
            $summary['pnr_ticket']         = $result['DATA']['pnr_ticket'];
            $summary['departure_time']     = $result['DATA']['departure_time'];
            $summary['departure_date']     = $result['DATA']['departure_date'];
            $summary['bag_amount']         = $result['DATA']['bag_amount'];
            $summary['price']              = $result['DATA']['price'];
            $summary['code']               = $result['DATA']['code'];
            $summary['symbol']             = $result['DATA']['symbol'];

            //I don't want to make a session
            // Session::put($summary);

            Session::flash('defaultSuccess', 'Success');
            Session::flash('textDefaultSuccess', ucfirst((strtolower($result['MESSAGE']))));

            return redirect()->route('summary');
        }else{
            Session::flash('defaultFailed', 'Create Summary Failed!');
            Session::flash('textDefaultFailed', ucfirst((strtolower($result['MESSAGE']))));
            return redirect()->route('passanger');
        }

    }
```

this is a function to hold data from the createPassanger function,

```
public function getDataSummary(){
        //function to save the post results from function createPassanger
        $data['title'] = "Summary";
        return view('v_summary', $data);
    }
```

this is a view from function getDataSummary,I do not want to save the data in the session

```
<div class="col-12">
            <table class="table borderless">
                <form action="{{route('payment')}}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="{{Session::get('order_id')}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{Session::get('price')}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{Session::get('passanger_email')}}">
                <tr>
                    <td>Passanger</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>{{Session::get('passanger_name')}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Passport</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>{{Session::get('passanger_passport')}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Country Issued</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>{{Session::get('airport_name')}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Airline</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>{{Session::get('airlines_name')}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Flight No</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>{{Session::get('flight_no')}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>PNR Ticket</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>{{Session::get('pnr_ticket')}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Departure Airport</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>{{Session::get('airport_name')}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Departure TIme</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>{{Session::get('departure_date')}} {{Session::get('departure_time')}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bag Required</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>{{Session::get('bag_amount')}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>{{Session::get('symbol')}} {{Session::get('price')}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-book btn-block">
                <p class="mb-0">NEXT</p>
            </button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

I have tried several times to get the results data from the post to be saved into getDataSummary but the result is an error of 500

Comment: if you don`t want to save in session, why don't to save data in a json file and in getSummaryData read the data from that Json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($result['STATUS_CODE'] == 200){
   self::getDataSummary($result);
}
```

And in your function receive this array

```
public function getDataSummary($result){
        //Handle your data
        $data['code'] = $result['DATA']['code'];
        return view('v_summary', $data);
}
```

Comment: this works fine, but how do I pass the data to the view (v_summary)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this by using this code

```
    public function createPassanger(Request $request){
        $api       = new Api;
        $input     = $request->all();
        $platform  = "W";
        $id_flight = Session::get('id_flight');
        $url       = config::get('constants.url')."api/passanger/add";

        //this is my post
        $post = array(
            "passanger_name"      => $input['name'], 
            "passanger_email"     => $input['email'],
            "passanger_passport"  => $input['passport'],
            "id_flight"           => $id_flight,
            "platform"            => $platform
        );

        $result = $api->post($url, $post);
        //this is results of the post
        if($result['STATUS_CODE'] == 200){
            $summary['id_summary']         = $result['DATA']['id_summary'];
            $summary['id_passanger']       = $result['DATA']['id_passanger'];
            $summary['id_flight']          = $result['DATA']['id_flight'];
            $summary['passanger_name']     = $result['DATA']['passanger_name'];
            $summary['passanger_passport'] = $result['DATA']['passanger_passport'];
            $summary['passanger_email']    = $result['DATA']['passanger_email'];
            $summary['order_id']           = $result['DATA']['order_id'];
            $summary['check_in']           = $result['DATA']['check_in'];
            $summary['status_booking']     = $result['DATA']['status_booking'];
            $summary['status']             = $result['DATA']['status'];
            $summary['member_id']          = $result['DATA']['member_id'];
            $summary['airlines_id']        = $result['DATA']['airlines_id'];
            $summary['airlines_name']      = $result['DATA']['airlines_name'];
            $summary['flight_no']          = $result['DATA']['flight_no'];
            $summary['airport_id']         = $result['DATA']['airport_id'];
            $summary['airport_name']       = $result['DATA']['airport_name'];
            $summary['pnr_ticket']         = $result['DATA']['pnr_ticket'];
            $summary['departure_time']     = $result['DATA']['departure_time'];
            $summary['departure_date']     = $result['DATA']['departure_date'];
            $summary['bag_amount']         = $result['DATA']['bag_amount'];
            $summary['price']              = $result['DATA']['price'];
            $summary['code']               = $result['DATA']['code'];
            $summary['symbol']             = $result['DATA']['symbol'];

            //I don't want to make a session
            // Session::put($summary);
            $file = storage_path().'/data.json';
            $handle = fopen($file, 'w+');
            fwrite($handle, '');
            fwrite($handle, json_encode($summary);
            fclose($handle);

            Session::flash('defaultSuccess', 'Success');
            Session::flash('textDefaultSuccess', ucfirst((strtolower($result['MESSAGE']))));

            return redirect()->route('summary');
        }else{
            Session::flash('defaultFailed', 'Create Summary Failed!');
            Session::flash('textDefaultFailed', ucfirst((strtolower($result['MESSAGE']))));
            return redirect()->route('passanger');
        }

    }
```

and to get data in view

```
    public function getDataSummary(){
          $jsondata = array();
           $file = storage_path() . '/data.json';
        $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
        $size = filesize($file);
        if ($size > 0) {
            $str = fread($handle, $size);
            $jsondata = json_decode($str,true);
        }
        fclose($handle);
        //function to save the post results from function createPassanger
        $data['title'] = "Summary";
        return view('v_summary', compact('jsondata','data'));
    }
```